# Explain about artifact resolution and token replay detection

Tags: adfs

I was going through ADFS docs and not able to understand both terms. Kindly help me about this.

Answer (score 1):

[Artefact resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Artifact_Resolution_Protocol).

Normally you authenticate and get a SAML token back. With this flow, you authenticate and get a pointer (the artefact) back. You then send this to the IDP via a back-channel e.g. SOAP and get the SAML token back.

[Token replay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/design/best-practices-for-secure-planning-and-deployment-of-ad-fs)

Token replay detection is a feature of AD FS that ensures that any attempt to replay a token request that is made to the Federation Service is detected and the request is discarded. Token replay detection is enabled by default. It works for both the WS-Federation passive profile and the Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) WebSSO profile by ensuring that the same token is never used more than once.

In other words, you can't send the same request twice. So a man in the middle can't get the token, alter it and send it again.